# ERR CONNECTION RESET while uploading file to S3 using aws-amplify storage

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Using aws-amplify storage to upload file to s3. But for some files I get this error

```
ConsoleLogger.js:133 [ERROR] 34:07.292 axios-http-handler Error: Network Error
    at LYNF.e.exports (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:80)
e._log @ ConsoleLogger.js:133
ConsoleLogger.js:141 [WARN] 34:07.293 AWSS3Provider - error uploading Error: Network Error
    at LYNF.e.exports (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:80)
```

Error is not consistent. It shows ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in network tab.

```
aws-amplify - 3.0.20
aws-amplify-react - 4.1.19
```